# How do I make a button change the web page on a WebKit Web View Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, web, webkit

How do I make a button change the web page on a WebKit Web View Xcode and yeah i'm talking about mac I would much appreciate it if you responded thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) changeWebPage
{
    [webView setMainFrameURL:@"www.google.com"];
}
```

Is that what you want?